# Puma don't start after capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, puma

I have a problem with my capistrano configuration. I have tried to follow severals tutorials without success. When I deploy, everything is good but at the end the deploy finishes without starting puma.

```
➜  api git:(master) ✗ cap production deploy
roicoeur@51.15.209.247's password:
rvm 1.29.9 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
ruby-3.0.0
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.061s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-a0da9a635c16c5f6b69d.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-a0da9a635c16c5f6b69d.sh
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.073s
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@gitlab.com:RoiCoeur/roi_coeur_api.git HEAD
      01 15fa8415b1bdebdf2fddc3b3562c9bc6d86be5a9       HEAD
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 2.533s
00:02 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/shared /data/roi_coeur_api/releases
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.020s
00:02 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/shared/public/assets
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.064s
00:02 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/shared/config
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.064s
00:03 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /data/roi_coeur_api/repo
00:03 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:RoiCoeur/roi_coeur_api.git
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.077s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
      02 From gitlab.com:RoiCoeur/roi_coeur_api
      02    471f1356..15fa8415  master     -> master
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 3.575s
00:07 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.071s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.954s
00:08 deploy:set_current_revision
      01 echo "15fa8415b1bdebdf2fddc3b3562c9bc6d86be5a9" > REVISION
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.068s
00:08 deploy:symlink:linked_files
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/config
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.066s
      02 ln -s /data/roi_coeur_api/shared/config/database.yml /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/config/database.yml
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.066s
      03 rm /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/config/secrets.yml
    ✔ 03 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.063s
      04 ln -s /data/roi_coeur_api/shared/config/secrets.yml /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/config/secrets.yml
    ✔ 04 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.065s
00:09 deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/public
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.065s
      02 rm -rf /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/public/assets
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.079s
      03 ln -s /data/roi_coeur_api/shared/public/assets /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/public/assets
    ✔ 03 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.049s
00:09 bundler:config
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle config --local deployment true
      01 Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): 3.0.0.
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 1.043s
      02 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle config --local path /data/roi_coeur_api/shared/bundle
      02 Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): 3.0.0.
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.987s
      03 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle config --local without development:test
      03 Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): 3.0.0.
    ✔ 03 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 1.009s
00:13 bundler:install
      The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied, skipping installation
00:13 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): 3.0.0.
      01 Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
      01 Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
      01 Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
      01 Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 148.221s
02:42 deploy:assets:backup_manifest
      01 mkdir -p /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/assets_manifest_backup
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.063s
      02 cp /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-8ff059873481df0a51f05274710bdeca.json /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855/assets_manifest_backup
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.071s
02:42 deploy:symlink:release
      01 ln -s /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210427082855 /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/current
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.060s
      02 mv /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/current /data/roi_coeur_api
    ✔ 02 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.276s
02:42 deploy:cleanup
      Keeping 5 of 6 deployed releases on 51.15.209.247
      01 rm -rf /data/roi_coeur_api/releases/20210426123044
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.086s
02:43 deploy:log_revision
      01 echo "Branch master (at 15fa8415b1bdebdf2fddc3b3562c9bc6d86be5a9) deployed as release 20210427082855 by remybeauperin" >> /data/roi_coeur_api/revisions.log
    ✔ 01 roicoeur@51.15.209.247 0.068s
➜  api git:(master)
```

You can see my capistrano config here:

```
# puma.rb
threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

port        ENV.fetch('PORT') { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV') { 'development' }

plugin :tmp_restart
####################################################


# deploy.rb
lock "~> 3.16.0"

set :application, 'app'
set :repo_url, 'git@gitlab.com:******/******.git'
set :deploy_to, -> { "/data/#{fetch(:application)}" }

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'].nil? ? :master : ENV['BRANCH']

# set :pty, true
  
set :ssh_options,
    forward_agent: true,
    keys: [
      File.join(ENV['HOME'], '.ssh', 'id_rsa')
    ]

append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'

after "deploy:updated", "deploy:migrate"
####################################################


# Capfile
require "capistrano/setup"

require "capistrano/deploy"

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rails'

require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"

require "capistrano/puma"
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
####################################################


# Gemfile
ruby '3.0.0'

source 'https://rubygems.org'
...

gem 'puma'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end
####################################################
```

I can't explain this problem. Can anyone see what it is?

**EDIT**

When I try to force the puma:restart in my deploy.rb I have this :

```
Caused by:
Don't know how to build task 'puma:restart' (See the list of available tasks with `cap --tasks`)
```

and effectively in `cap --tasks` i have nothing else for Puma cmd :

```
...
cap git:wrapper                    # Upload the git wrapper script, this script guarantees that we can script git without getting an interactive prompt
cap install                        # Install Capistrano, cap install STAGES=staging,production
cap puma:config                    # Setup Puma config file
cap rvm:check                      # Prints the RVM and Ruby version on the target host
```

Comment: Are there any puma logs on your remote server?\
One possible problem is capistrano failed to start the puma server,\
checkout your puma logs (or puma error log) and see if there is words like `early termination of worker`. According to my last experience,\
I forgot to remove byebug from my codebase and byebug only installed in develop environment.\
I removed it and then works fine.

Comment: the production mode on local is launch without problem... And my logs look good

Comment: Hello @Oscar I have edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked my project and the differences are

```
## Gemfile
gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: 'seuros/capistrano-puma'

## Capfile
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma, load_hooks: true
```

Comment: The same thing... Have you `ruby 3.0.0`, 'capistrano 3.16.0' and `capistrano3-puma 5.0.4` ? Perhaps is a version problem.

Comment: my ruby version is `2.6.0` and capistrano3-puma version is `4.0.0`

Comment: It would be a problem in the version... I don't know what I must try